# Install optional sage package (nauty) on archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, sage-math

tl;dr: how can I install optional sage packages on archlinux?

Quoting the Arch wiki [page for sage](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SageMath):

> Most if not all of the standard sage packages
>   are available as Arch packages and exposed as
>   (optional) dependencies of sagemath, so there 
>   is no need to install them with `sage -i`.

Alas, the (very) nauty package is an **optional** one,
and so cannot be installed from with pacman.

The error I get when trying the standard `sage -i nauty` (either with or without sudo) is

```
/usr/bin/sage: line 297: ./sage: No such file or directory
```

This is documented in the [talk page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Talk:SageMath) (of the Arch Wiki) for Sage (as in "this happens"). That page does not discuss workarounds.

So far I have been unable to find any reference or guidance in installing optional packages.

Any reference would be warmly welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `pacman -Si sagemath` lists all optional dependencies for Sagemath available through pacman (see the [archlinux wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SageMath#Installation), thanks Lahwaacz!).

```
$ pacman -Si sagemath
...
Optional Deps   : 
...
           nauty: for generating some classes of graphs
...
```

So all that is needed is to install nauty: `sudo pacman -Syu nauty`, and you may run it to your heart's content (examples [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_generators.html#sage.graphs.graph_generators.GraphGenerators.nauty_geng)).